# enforce 2 space indentation with jshint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

I have a .jshintrc file with this config:

```
{
  "indent": 2
}
```

And I have a js file that looks like this:

```
var hello = angular.module('hello', ['hello.controllers']);

angular.module('hello.controllers', []).
controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  'use strict';

  // hello msg
    var helloMsg = 'Some Awesome Things';
  $scope.helloMsg = helloMsg;
}]);
```

And when I run jshint on the file, no error is thrown.

Notice that the line `var helloMsg = 'Some Awesome Things';` is indented two extra spaces.

What do I need to do so that jshint throws an error on the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using version >= 2.5.0? If so, seems they removed it:

> indent no longer provides warnings about indentation levels

https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.5.0